# Comparing (possible) multiple values from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I need to display rows that do not have the same exact values from 2 tables, and only show what is different. To illustrate:

**Table 1**

```
Item_col      val_col
 Item1          1a
 Item1          1b
 Item1          2a
 Item2          2b
 Item2          2a
 Item3          1a
```

**Table 2**

```
Item_col       val_col
 Item1          1b
 Item2          2b
 Item2          2a
 Item3          1b
 Item3          1a
 Item3          2a
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Item_col       val_col
 Item1          1a
 Item1          2a
 Item3          1b
 Item           2a
```

In the above examples, the result filtered out the rows that have the same Item_col and val_col information. I've used a combination of joins and where clauses but I'm not getting the results I need. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this - I think the code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   table2 t2
                     WHERE  t2.Item_Col = t1.Item_Col
                            AND t1.val_col = t2.val_col )
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    table2 t2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   table1 t1
                     WHERE  t2.Item_Col = t1.Item_Col
                            AND t1.val_col = t2.val_col );
```

Here's a [full fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kphzfsU8r6QarD8uh85roH/0) demonstrating it.

Comment: Let me try it out and let you know if it worked for my needs. Thanks for your quick reply Icarus!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Item_col = t2.Item_col AND t1.val_col = t2.val_col
WHERE t2.Item_col IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.Item_col = t2.Item_col AND t1.val_col = t2.val_col
WHERE t1.Item_col IS NULL
```